# php ($foo > 0) OR ($foo >= 1)

Tags: php

I have always wondered what is best practice when checking numbers are 1 or greater.

```
IF($foo > 0)
```

OR

```
IF($foo >= 1)
```

Which one should I be using? They both appear to work the same.

Comment: It works the same only if $foo is integer.

Comment: `0.001 > 0` vs `0.001 >= 1`

Comment: @Esailija hadn't thought of that situation and guess that defeats my whole question. But in the event we was only dealing with whole numbers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When it comes to performance, you would like to use `>=` instead of `>`.

My benchmark in pseudo:

```
for 100000x {
    time result of 5 > 0
}

for 100000x {
    time result of 5 >= 1
}
```

Edit: and as William in the comments suggested to time the whole for-loop, that's exactly what happened. I added up all the times together which gave me the exact same result as timing the whole for-loop at once. So basically I did the same. (FYI. I benchmarked William his suggestion, it had the same results. Trust me, I'm an engineer)

My results:

```
          >                 >=
x100000 | 198.63224029541 | 191.68829917908
In MS
```

So, when it comes to speed and you are using integers (see the great answers above!), `>=` would be faster. But, consider the consequences! It's only `7ms` over a `100.000` tests. But, when you are having a couple of million records to check...

**edit**

After a couple of more times running the benchmark, I get even bigger differences. Differences like `10`, `15` and even `20` ms! Nothing was changed, apparently my processor was busy, but it is good sharing it with you guys.

Comment: I hope you didn't implement it exactly as your pseudocode suggests, since it won't be an accurate test. Timing every single comparison will take more time than the actual comparison, and be inaccurate. You're better off doing 100k > runs, then timing that as a whole against 100k >= runs.

Comment: @WilliamLawnStewart Yup, that's exactly what I did. I will change it, I though this would make sense. But probably it did not..

Answer (score 3):

The ultimately correct one is:

```
if ($foo >= 1) { }
```

It's clear, concise and works for any number type you throw at it (all two of them).

Here are some alternatives for *integer only* comparisons; btw, none of them yield better performance (fact) or readability (in my opinion).

```
if ($foo) { 
    // anything that's not zero, regardless of sign
}

if ($foo != 0) {
    // same as above, but forces the left operand to be casted to number
}

if ($foo > 0) {
    // anything that's above zero and therefore greater or equal to one
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
                     -1      0       0.5      1
IF($foo > 0)         false   false   true     true
IF($foo >= 1)        false   false   false    true
IF($foo)             true    false   true     true
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is checking that a value *is greater than or equal to 1*, then there isn't even a decision to be made here.  The **only** choice is `x >= 1`, both logically and semantically speaking.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you are using integers or floating point.

There is little point to picking one based on performance benefits.

After seeing Jelmer's claim, I wrote a benchmark to test and see if there is a meaningful difference.

Here is the exact code for the benchmark I ran:

```
<?php

echo '&gt;= VS &gt;<br/>';

for($j = 0; $j < 100; $j++)
{

    $start = microtime(true);

    for($i = 1000000; $i > 0; $i--)
    {

    }

    $midpoint = microtime(true);

    for($i = 1000000; $i >= 1; $i--)
    {

    }

    $end = microtime(true);

    $with_equals = $end - $midpoint;
    $no_equals = $midpoint - $start;

    echo $with_equals.' VS '.$no_equals.'<br/>';

    if($with_equals < $no_equals)
    {
        $with_equals_wins++;
    }
    elseif($with_equals > $no_equals)
    {
        $no_equals_wins++;
    }

}

echo '<br/>TOTAL WINS<br/>&gt;= - '.$with_equals_wins.' VS &gt; - '.$no_equals_wins;
```

On my Intel i7 Sandy Bridge laptop running Windows 7 x64 and XAMPP 1.7.3, I then ran the benchmark several times and got the following results: (I made sure to turn off Turbo Boost so that the CPU clocks were stable)

```
TOTAL WINS
>= - 26 VS > - 74

TOTAL WINS
>= - 21 VS > - 79

TOTAL WINS
>= - 22 VS > - 78
```

Note that my results are the opposite of what Jelmer got.

If there is any kind of even slightly meaningful performance difference, then it likely depends on the specific hardware and software environment in which the code runs.